# Is there a single word for combining two things for enhanced synergy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper where two things are combined to be more efficient than each individually. I think I've used "integrated" 30 times so far.

What other words can I use to mean the same thing?

Comment: Did you look in a thesaurus for 'integrate'?

Comment: Your own term *synergy* describes that '*sum is greater than its parts*' idea.

Comment: _Confluence_ and _resonate_.

Answer (score 4):

*Merged*, *combined* and (my favourite) *melded* are all single words that have the meaning of mixing two things together. However, I don't think any of them imply that the combination works better than the original items.

In some circumstances (but not in general) the word *chained* may also be appropriate, for example when the two "items" are actually processes that can be arranged serially in a workflow such that the output of one becomes the input of the other.

If you don't mind an idiomatic phrase, you can say "The combination of the items formed a *whole that was greater than the sum of its parts*" which does bring across the idea of synergy.

If it's in a scientific or other drily technical context, you could just express it very literally as: "the combination of the items exhibited synergy". *Synergy* already means exactly what you want it to mean:

Synergy (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synergy)

> synergy
>
> 1. The interaction of two or more agents or forces so that their combined effect is greater than the sum of their individual effects.
> 2. Cooperative interaction among groups, especially among the acquired subsidiaries or merged parts of a corporation, that creates an enhanced combined effect.
> 3. An instance of either such interaction.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the word "synergistic" which means two things working together for enhanced effect greater than the sum of their individual effects.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you add a link to your definition? Also, the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) is useful if you're just starting out.